# PLSQL: Validating an XML CLOB

Tags: xml, oracle, plsql, clob, xmltype

I have XML data in a CLOB column like below:

```
<JOURNAL_DET_NS_REP>
    <N9 xsi:nil="1"/>
    <N8 xsi:nil="1"/>
    <N3>2020</N3>
    ....
    <C1>01</C1>
    <C38>Production</C38>
    <C39>Assortment</C39>
    <C40>Fixed Asse</C40>
    <C41>Project</C41>
    <C44>Business</C44>
    ....
</JOURNAL_DET_NS_REP>
```

What I want to do is validate this XML data whether it is well formed.

This is a customer's already existing column data and I am just using it.

In this XML CLOB data, there is no xml tag so I tried appending it and then converting the XML CLOB to XMLType.

```
 DECLARE
   clob_rec   CLOB;
   xml_header VARCHAR2(100);
   x          xmltype;

   CURSOR get_xml_clob_ IS
      SELECT data
      FROM   xml_report_data_tab
      WHERE  report_id = 'DET_REP'
      AND    result_key = '15332672';

BEGIN

   OPEN get_xml_clob_;
   FETCH get_xml_clob_
      INTO clob_rec;
   CLOSE get_xml_clob_;

   xml_header := '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>';
   clob_rec   := TO_CLOB(xml_header) || clob_rec;

   x := xmltype(clob_rec);

   --I will use x and do other stuff here

END;
```

**But when I run this script, I get an error as below.**

[image]

Can someone help me figure out what I am doing wrong?
This is Oracle Version: 11.2.0.2.0.

Comment: The namespace used somewhere in the XML is not declared. The error message is quite verbose and clear. You need to add some root XML element (to wrap the document) and append `xmlns:xsi` declaration to it.

Comment: The CLOB you shared is not well formed. It uses namespaces that are not declared. Missing the XML declaration is not a problem (unless you consider it to be one); but missing namespace declarations, when namespaces are actually used, is definitely going to be a problem. I would just say that the input you showed us is indeed not well formed.